# Charset UTF-8 and CodePage 65001 does not return correct in ASP Classic

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic

In a normal ASP Classic document I set CodePage = 65001 and Charset = UTF-8, but somehow it does not return correct charset (Danish) - document is saved as UTF-8 encoding i Visual Studio Code

The Code :

```
<% 
  Response.CodePage = 65001
  Response.ContentType = "text/html"
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"

  Response.Write "The Session code page is " & Session.CodePage & "<BR>" 
  Response.Write "The Response code page is " & Response.CodePage & "<BR>" 
  Response.Write "The Response Charset is " & Response.CharSet & "<BR>"
  Response.Write "<br>"
  Response.Write "Page with æ ø å"
  Response.End
%>
```

.. it should return the danish æ ø å, but returns the following:

```
The Session code page is 65001
The Response code page is 65001
The Response Charset is UTF-8

Page with Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥
```

Anyone knows what the heck is going on here? .. ALL other pages in the same site works fine, and I have also tried copy the code to another new file, but that does not help!

Here is the entire ASP page content:

```html
<% 
  Response.CodePage = 65001
  Response.ContentType = "text/html"
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"

  Response.Write "The Session code page is " & Session.CodePage & "<BR>" 
  Response.Write "The Response code page is " & Response.CodePage & "<BR>" 
  Response.Write "The Response Charset is " & Response.CharSet & "<BR>"
  Response.Write "<br>"
  Response.Write "Page with æ ø å"
  Response.End


    Dim strUser, strPassword, domain, AuthenticateUser, InsertToEFPLogSQL, InsertToEFPLogObj, InsertToEFPLog, strQuery, oConn, cmd

    strUser = Request.Form("strUserName")
    strPassword = Request.Form("strPassword")


    Dim SettingsDeveloperConn
    Set SettingsDeveloperConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    SettingsDeveloperConn.ConnectionString="<CONNECTIONSTRING>"
    SettingsDeveloperConn.Open

    Dim SettingsDeveloperSQL, objSettingsDeveloper

    SettingsDeveloperSQL = "SELECT DeveloperAdminEmail, DeveloperAdminHash FROM EFP_Settings WHERE ID = 1;"

    Set objSettingsDeveloper = SettingsDeveloperConn.Execute(SettingsDeveloperSQL)

    IF strUser = objSettingsDeveloper("DeveloperAdminEmail") THEN

      IF strPassword = objSettingsDeveloper("DeveloperAdminHash") THEN

        AuthenticateUser = true
        Session("UserIsAuthenticated") = "true"
        Session("ADUserEmail") = strUser
        Session("DeveloperAdmin") = "true"

            
          Set InsertToEFPLog = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
          InsertToEFPLog.ConnectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING"
          InsertToEFPLog.Open

          InsertToEFPLogSQL = "INSERT INTO EFP_LOG (DataString ,Operation ,Area ,ChangedBy, ContactID, ADdisplayName) VALUES ('" & strUser & " loggede p&aring;', 'Login', '', 'Developer Admin', '','Developer Admin');"

          response.Write InsertToEFPLogSQL
          Response.End

          Set InsertToEFPLogObj = InsertToEFPLog.Execute(InsertToEFPLogSQL)
          InsertToEFPLog.Close
          Set InsertToGEFPLog = Nothing


        Response.Redirect "index.asp"

      ELSE

        AuthenticateUser = false
        Session("tmpstrUserName") = strUser
        Response.Redirect "login.asp?AuthRejected=yes"

      END IF

    ELSE


    'on error resume next
    domain = "<DOMAIN CONTROLLER>"

    ' assume failure
    AuthenticateUser = false

    strQuery = "SELECT cn FROM 'LDAP://" & domain & "' WHERE objectClass='*' "
    set oConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOOBJECT"
    oConn.Properties("User ID") = strUser
    oConn.Properties("Password") = strPassword
    oConn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = true
    oConn.open "DS Query", strUser, strPassword

    set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    set cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery
    on error resume next
    set oRS = cmd.Execute
    if oRS.bof or oRS.eof then
        AuthenticateUser = false
        Session("tmpstrUserName") = strUser
        Response.Redirect "login.asp?AuthRejected=yes"
    else

        Session("ADUserEmail") = strUser

        Dim arr
        arr = Split(Session("ADUserEmail"), "@")
        Session("ADUserName") = arr(0)


        Dim GetPrivilegeLevelConn
        Set GetPrivilegeLevelConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        GetPrivilegeLevelConn.ConnectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING"
        GetPrivilegeLevelConn.Open

        Dim GetPrivilegeLevelSQL, objGetPrivilegeLevel

        GetPrivilegeLevelSQL = "SELECT * FROM EFP_SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS WHERE PrivilegeUserID = '" & arr(0) & "';"

        Set objGetPrivilegeLevel = GetPrivilegeLevelConn.Execute(GetPrivilegeLevelSQL)

        if objGetPrivilegeLevel.bof or objGetPrivilegeLevel.eof then

          AuthenticateUser = false
          EnrollRequestUser = true
          Session("EnrollRequestUser") = "true"
          Session("tmpstrUserName") = Session("ADUserName")
          Response.Redirect "index.asp?EnrollRequestUser=yes"
        
        else

          Session("EFPPrivilegeLevel") = objGetPrivilegeLevel("PrivilegeLevelID")
          Session("EFPPrivilegeName") = objGetPrivilegeLevel("PrivilegeLevelName")

          AuthenticateUser = true
          Session("UserIsAuthenticated") = "true"

          
          Set InsertToEFPLog = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
          InsertToEFPLog.ConnectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING"
          InsertToEFPLog.Open

          InsertToEFPLogSQL = "INSERT INTO EFP_LOG (DataString, Operation, ChangedBy, ADdisplayName) VALUES ('" & Session("ADUserEmail") & " loggede på;', 'Login', '" & arr(0) & "','" & arr(0) & "');"

          Set InsertToEFPLogObj = InsertToEFPLog.Execute(InsertToEFPLogSQL)
          InsertToEFPLog.Close
          Set InsertToGEFPLog = Nothing

          response.Write InsertToEFPLogSQL
          Response.End

          Response.Redirect "index.asp"

          set objGetPrivilegeLevel = nothing
          set GetPrivilegeLevelConn = nothing 

          end if

    end if
    set oRS = nothing
    set oConn = nothing

    END IF
%>
```

**UPDATE!!!**

I tried adding a default HTML template, and added the ASP code and some normal text .. The result is that ASP does not return correct encoding, but HTML does ..

The new code :

```html
<% 
  Response.CodePage = 65001
  Response.ContentType = "text/html"
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <% Response.Write "The Session code page is " & Session.CodePage & "<BR>" %>
  <% Response.Write "The Response code page is " & Response.CodePage & "<BR>"  %>
  <% Response.Write "The Response Charset is " & Response.CharSet & "<BR>" %>
  <% Response.Write "<br>" %>
  <% Response.Write "Page with æ ø å" %>
<br>
<br>Hej æ ø å

  </body>
</html>
<% Response.End %>
```

Which returns :

```
The Session code page is 65001
The Response code page is 65001
The Response Charset is UTF-8

Page with Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥

Hej æ ø å
```

**NEW UPDATE**

@user692942 actually nailed it with the link to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677180/convert-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-classic-asp) .. what fixed it for me was actually changing all charset and Codepage to this:

```
<%@Language="VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>

<% 
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

THANK YOU @user692942! :-)

Comment: You haven’t told IIS how to process the actual page just the responses. If the page has been saved as `Windows-1252` for example but IIS tries processing it as `UTF-8` you will still get an encoding mismatch.

Comment: No .. Neigther setting "text/html; charset=utf-8" for .asp in IIS Mime Type or adding <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" /> in web.config has no effect, it still returns faulty characters.

Comment: Thank you @user692942 for pointing me to that article, in the end it fixed it for me .. see my "NEW UPDATE" in my post :-) .. and please post an answer so that I can accept it :-)

Comment: Glad that worked for you consider leaving an upvote if you found it useful.

Comment: I did yes :-) .. unfortunately I dobble clicked the upvote and is unable to redo it again, i did not know that ;-(

Comment: That is the case on comments but on questions and answers if you vote then unvote it does allow you to vote again but if you vote and it passes 5 minutes the vote will be locked in.